# How do I decipher the Mine Blocks enchantment table alphabet?

Tags: mine-blocks

In *Mine Blocks*, I want to get a Fire Aspect Sword, but I don't know how to read the alphabet used in the enchantment table.

**How do I decipher the Mine Blocks enchantment table alphabet?**

Answer (score 1):

I googled a bit and found this alphabet. It seems that the minecraft/Mine Blocks enchantment language origins from the game Commander Keen. I do not think the letters spell out any word, therefore I don't think you can translate it into anything useful (i could be mistaken though). Anyway here is the 
alphabet  .

[image]

Comment: Uh Thank you uh...Mineblocks And mine Craft is diffrent, Mineblocks is a online 2-D Game and minecraft,you need to download it,bro.It cost money too.

Comment: i know they are different, but read somewhere that they use the same alphabet when it comes to enchanting.